# output of the structure size using bitfields

Tags: c++, c

```
#pragma pack(2)
struct a{
  unsigned a:1;
  unsigned b:1;
  int c;
  unsigned d:4;
  unsigned :4;
  unsigned e:1;
  unsigned :0;
  unsigned f:1;} ;

int main()
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(struct a));
}
```

The output of the following program comes to be 16 when pragma pack is not used but is 10 when pragma pack is used.please explain how is this?

Comment: For curiosity's sake: Are you compiling for a 32-bit or 64-bit platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `#pragma`s are compiler-specific so without you specifying your compiler and CPU (and perhaps compiler version and commandline options) we can only speculate.

But, a plausible explanation is that, for the "pack(2)" version:

```
#pragma pack(2)
struct a{ 
    unsigned a:1;    // at byte offset 0, could be least- or most-significant bit
    unsigned b:1;    // also in byte 0, besides a
    int c;           // explicitly requested this int be mis-aligned at byte 2
                     //   seems you've 32-bit ints, so 4-byte are 2,3,4,5
    unsigned d:4;    // at byte 6
    unsigned :4;     // also fits in byte 6
    unsigned e:1;    // in byte 7
    unsigned :0;     // requests following field be aligned for unsigned type
                     //   your unsigned int must be 32-bits, so this means
                     //   following field must start at 0, 4, 8, 12 etc.
                     //   so: skips rest of byte 7 and moves to 8
    unsigned f:1;    // occupies one bit of byte 8
};
```

Because the packing is "2", and already using the 9 bytes from [0] to [8], the `sizeof(a)` is rounded up to 10.

Without your pragma the default would be 4 bytes / 32-bits.  So, the first `int` is aligned on a 32-bit address for faster access, skipping 2 and 3 and occupying bytes 4, 5, 6, 7.  That pushes `e` along by those 2 skipped byte into in byte 9, and `:0` forces the following field to be in byte 12.  The total size is then rounded to the 32-bit word size, so from 13 (for bytes [0] to [12]), up to 16.

Answer (score 4):

The effect of `#pragma pack(2)` is purely implementation defined, so
you really should read the documentation about it (but I can sort of
guess).  Without the pragma, according to the standard, the presence of
a non-bitfield element or a bitfield with size 0 causes the compiler to
advance to the next "unit", so in your structure, `a` and `b` are in the
first unit, `c` in the second, `d` and `e` in the third, and `f` in the
fourth.  Given that the size is 16, I'd guess 4 byte units (which is
almost universal today).  With `#pragma pack(2)`, I'd guess that the
basic unit is two bytes, rather than four.  And that this doesn't change
the size of an `int`, so `c` remains four bytes, but the other units
above are only two.  Which gives a total of ten bytes, so my guess
probably isn't too far off.